# Fourier Transform of Weak Derivative

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform, weak-derivatives

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $f\in W^{1,p}(U)$. I wish to prove that
$$
\mathcal{F}\left[(D_{x_k}f)(x)\right] = i \xi_k\, \mathcal{F}\left[f(x)\right]
$$
where $D_{x_k}f$ is the weak derivative of $f$ with respect to $x_k$.

My naive attempt is to approach it directly:
$$
\mathcal{F}\left[(D_{x_k}f)(x)\right] = \int_U\left(D_{x_k}f(x)\right)e^{-i\xi\cdot x}\,dx
$$
Since $e^{-i\xi\cdot x}\notin C^{\infty}_c(U)$ so we can't use the definiton of weak derivative directly. Also, since we are dealing with weak derivative instead of usual partial derivative, I am not sure how if we can use integration by parts in the usual sense.

How should I proceed with this? Or is there a better approach than to deal with this integration head-on?

Comment: How do you define the Fourier transform of $f \in L^p(U)$ when $U \neq \Bbb R^n$? And if $f \not\in L^1(U)$?

Comment: I assume $U = \mathbb{R}^n$. (1) You could consider $\eta(x) e^{i \xi \cdot x}$ instead (with $\eta$ being a cutoff function), and then pass to the limit (with cutting off bigger and bigger balls). (2) Weak derivatives are _defined_ by integration by parts, so how else could you use it if not by integrating by parts?